# Is it possible to make gradlew to work with nexus?

Tags: nexus, gradlew, android-build

I have a build machine for Android app. This machine has no access to the Internet.

There is a local nexus repository. Application gradle set up to load dependencies from this nexus repository and it works fine.

But I also need gradlew to load from that nexus repository too.

I've tried to set `distributionUrl` to local nexus url and it works - distribution is installed and daemon is started.

But next it fails to load `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml` with timeout

Is there a way to redirect all gradle requests to nexus repositories?

Comment: @Selven, nope...

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all Gradle requests to your Nexus repository, you can add the following to your gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<hostname>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<port>
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

Replace  and  with the hostname and port of your Nexus repository. This will tell Gradle to use your local Nexus repository for all dependencies, including the addons_list-5.xml file that you are currently having trouble loading.

It's also a good idea to make sure that your Nexus repository is properly configured and has all the necessary dependencies. You can check the logs of your Nexus repository to see if there are any errors or issues that might be preventing Gradle from accessing the dependencies it needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't helped me. As I understand, nesus ain't a proxy server. It is maven repository. So it just rejects proxy requests.